# string substitutions: all occurrences

Tags: zsh, string

A simple question, but I can't find the answer. the zsh documentation overwhelms me :-(

```
function z ()
{
  echo ${1:s/the/THE}
}

$ z thethethe
THEthethe
```

...

How can I get *all* 'the' to be replaced with 'THE', not just the first occurrence?  With zsh it's the easiest things that seem to be the hardest to find examples for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many answers, but none of them are comprehensive, so I felt like adding an answer that sums it all up.

#### Lower/Uppercasing

If you are trying to uppercase the string, the simplest way is to use:

```
> str="thethethe"
> upper="$str:u"
> echo $upper
THETHETHE
```

(Not part of the original question, but just in case) If you are trying to lowercase, the same goes for `:l`.

#### Replacing substrings

If you want to replace a single occurrence, use this:

```
> str="thethethe"
> echo ${str/the/man}
manthethe
```

If you add an extra slash between the variable and the test to substitute, it will replace all the occurrences:

```
> str="thethethe"
> echo ${str//the/man}
manmanman
```

Another option is to use the history modifiers, just like Gilles suggested:

```
> str="thethethe"
> echo ${str:gs/the/man}
manmanman
```

Answer (score 41):

This is a [history expansion modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers), so add the `g` modifier immediately before `s`.

```
print -r -- ${1:gs/the/THE}
```

Alternatively, use the [parameter expansion syntax](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) where a double slash means a global substitution. In this case, the part after `//` is a wildcard pattern, whereas history expansion substitution takes a literal string (unless the `histsubstpattern` option is enabled).

```
print -r -- ${1//the/THE}
```

Comment: Is it possible to write the syntax twice to apply two replacements in one line?

Comment: @Niing In zsh, yes, you can write things like `${${var//up/down}//left/right}` which replaces all occurrences of `up` by `down` and all occurrences of `left` by `right`.

Answer (score 10):

This should do the job:

```
VARIABLE=thethethe
print -r -- ${VARIABLE//the/THE}
THETHETHE
```

Comment: I am not seeing a difference with and without the double dash in second position.  What is the need for this?

Answer (score 5):

Thereyago, it had to be simple:

```
print -r -- ${1//the/THE}
```

... the double slash does it, and you can't fool around with " :s "

BTW, I'd sure like to thank the 'StackExchange' sites for existing. Of all the zillions of places one might ask a question, these are by far the best--one not only almost always gets answers, but those answers are invariably of the highest quality.

Answer (score 1):

// works perfect if you're only trying to replace a specific word to all caps while leaving the rest of it untouched. If you are trying to convert everything to uppercase, you can use ":u" on the variable

```
SOME_ENV_VALUE='thethethe'
print -r -- $SOME_ENV_VALUE:u # outputs: THETHETHE
```

You can verify which modifiers you have available in the zsh expansion and substitution manual

```
man zshexpn
```

Or with

```
info zsh modifiers
```

If you have the `info` pages installed.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to help people and myself, since I just recovered from some accidental deletion:

```bash
readonly question="${@:2}"
question_json="${question//$'\n'/\\\n}"    # replace newline with: \n
question_json="${question_json//\"/\\\"}"  # replace double-quote with: \"
```

Comment: In zsh, which is the  shell discussed in this Q&A, that replaces newlines with `\\n`, not `\n`.  That `${@:2}` is more ksh93 syntax. In zsh, you'd use `$@[3,-1]` or `$argv[3,-1]` (though it now supports the ksh93 syntax as well for compatibility with that shell). In zsh, that will join the elements with the first character of `$IFS`. If you wanted `$question` to have the 3rd to last positional parameters joined with a space character and with newlines replaced with `\n` and `"` with `\"`, you'd do: `question_json=${${(j[ ])argv[3,-1]//$'\n'/\\n}/\"/\\\"}`.

Comment: To do proper JSON encoding, you'd use something like `jq`: `question_json=$(jq -n --arg a "${(j[ ])argv[3,-1]}" '$a')` (here assuming  positional parameters contain properly UTF-8 encoded text and no NUL characters).

Comment: What is JSON anyway?

Comment: @RayAndrews I'm not sure whether or not you already have an answer in mind because it's very much a common sense, but anyway I meant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON. I was building an app for ChatGPT and they require the data format to be written in JSON.